# How can I configure GIMP 2.8 to be a single window in XMonad?

Tags: gimp, xmonad

I'm trying to get GIMP to display as a single window in XMonad. Currently, it's floating strangely in front of every other display and I can't use it.

I have tried reading this:

http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Xmonad/General_xmonad.hs_config_tips#Gimp

But it seems this is for versions of GIMP before 2.8 when there wasn't the option to have GIMP use only 1 window. Because of this, it's an XMonad problem, not a GIMP one.

How can I do this?

Comment: Whats your Xmonad version?

Comment: @Nima version 0.10-4

Comment: Ok can you provide your xmonad.hs?

Comment: @Nima The only thing I have changed in it are different keybindings, otherwise it's the default.

Comment: I wish GIMP/Steam/Evince would stop trying to badly manage windows and leave the window manager to do its job!

Answer (score 10):

Gimp 2.8 has an option under the "Windows" menu titled "Single Window Mode".  Check that, and restart Gimp.

[image: pic of option in gimp]

Comment: Uh, maybe a whoops... Does this option not help with Xmonad?  Go on people, flame me... {sigh}

Comment: I have that option checked but XMonad is treating it strangely and floating it in front of everything else.

Comment: @Pubby: Try to dock the floating windows to the right and left sides of the central window.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I had the same problem and figured out the best solution (at least for me) while I was looking online for one: Simply go to window -> single-window mode.
Then make the window go to fullscreen with mod + t (this is the default binding).

I know the first part was already answered, but that part alone only gets all gimp windows together in one, it still is a floating window, and I don't like that in my xmonad.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try again.

[How to unfloat Gimp](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Xmonad/General_xmonad.hs_config_tips#Gimp)

The link has quite a bit of information on using Xmonad.  Several references to this page.

One more, specifically concerning Gimp:

[look in the responses below the main part of the article](http://xmonad.wordpress.com/2009/03/08/xmonad-and-the-gimp/)

The relevant part:

But xmonad also floats all gimp windows by default. I use this to avoid floating the main two windows:

```
managehook = composeall [
    gimp "toolbox" --> (ask >>= doF . W.sink),
    gimp "image-window" --> (ask >>= doF . W.sink),
    manageHook defaultConfig
]
where gimp win = (className =? “Gimp” (fmap (win `isSuffixOf`) role))
role = stringProperty “WM_WINDOW_ROLE”
```

Comment: I think I'm just going to quit now while I'm ahead... I just posted the SAME link... {Sigh}  I'm terribly sorry to have bothered you..  Any chance on some love for the SECOND link?